# Do any automated browser testing tools support iOS and Android browsers?

Tags: automated-tests, mobile-website

I am aware of both Selenium and Watir, but neither seem to offer support for iOS and Android browsers (including touch gestures)

Is there anything out there that does? Any recommendations?

If there is no existing software, can anyone recommend a good approach for automated testing of mobile browsers (over and above JS unit tests)?

Comment: What are you testing (rendering capabilities, performance, etc.)?

Comment: @Inspire48 Functional testing. Analogous to what you'd use selenium for in the environments it supports. Ideally for use in a continuous integration environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation of the WebDriver says that Selenium (to-be Selenium 2.0) [supports both Android and iOS, the real device and the simulator](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverForMobileBrowsers) (though, obviously, you need a developer license to use it on a iOS physical device). From there on, it's just a matter of using Selenium 2.0 and writing tests for it.