# It is possible to automate mobile sites tests on mobile devices with Watir?

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile, safari, watir

I need to test mobile sites on real devices (iPhone Safari) or emulator (Safari on xCode simulator). It is possible?

Thanks.

Comment: A quick Googling turned up http://watirwebdriver.com/mobile-devices/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676374/do-any-automated-browser-testing-tools-support-ios-and-android-browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Code samples are here: https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-MobileFrontend/tree/master/tests/acceptance

If you have specific questions, ask.